# Long bootup time with bridge configured in netplan in 18.04

Tags: boot, networking, netplan, systemd-networkd

In Ubuntu 18.04 the default network configuration is done with netplan.
I have a setup which creates a bridge interface at startup, see below.

It all works great, except that during startup it runs into a timeout of about 2 minutes. After the timeout it finishes the startup, and the
system runs without problems.

For 2 minutes it prints this message on the console (also present in /var/log/boot.log)

```
A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured
```

I have several systems with Ubuntu 18.04 and netplan, but only the ones with a this bridge interface have this problem.

Does anyone else see this too?

This is my netplan config

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bridges:
    testbr0:
      addresses:
      - 10.82.0.1/24
```

BTW. I'm using this bridge for LXD. At startup there are no LXD containers yet that use this bridge.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon this exact problem.
In my case it was because one of the interfaces in the bridge didn't have a network cable plugged in so networkd/networkctl tried to get it up (because it is defined in netplan) but failed.

I would guess that not having it defined at all in your netplan configuration causes the same issue. Perhaps networkd/networkctl is waiting for a "link is up" signal from a bridge that will never send one because there is no interface in it?

The solution in my case was to add `optional: true` in the interface definition (not the bridge).

In your case, with a bridge without any interface, the solution might be to do it at the bridge level:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bridges:
    testbr0:
      addresses:
      - 10.82.0.1/24
      optional: true
```

For good measure I added the directive to all interfaces in that bridge.